# Filtering an array of string within an array of objects with an array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, laravel, vue.js

Sorry if it's been asked before but i couldn't find a solution despite searching in the website.
I have an array of objects (restaurants) with many properties. One of them (tags) is an array of string. Then i have another array of strings (filters).
The result i need after filtering is an array of restaurants whose tags includes all the filters (this is made reactive with VueJS, there can be any amount of filters including zero).

I'm pretty sure there is a simple solution that i'm currently missing, combining some loops, filter() and some()/includes().

Here is the closest I've been to the result i want (in what probably is a very inefficient way), but it's buggy if you choose some pattern of filter in a certain combination and order(it splice a restaurant that shouldn't be spliced, I have no clue why).

```
  if (restaurants) {
    filters.forEach((filter) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < restaurants.length; i++) {
        const restaurant = restaurants[i]

        if (!checkedFilters.includes(filter)) {
          checkedFilters.push(filter);
        }

        if (restaurant.tags.some((tag) => tag.name === filter)) {
          if (!filteredRestaurants.includes(restaurant)) {
            filteredRestaurants.push(restaurant)
          }
        }
      }
    })

    for (let i = 0; i < filteredRestaurants.length; i++) {
      const filteredRestaurant = filteredRestaurants[i];

      checkedFilters.forEach((checkedFilter) => {
        if (!filteredRestaurant.tags.some((tag) => tag.name === checkedFilter)) {
          filteredRestaurants.splice(i, 1)
        }
      })
    }

    return filteredRestaurants
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you have a loop to remove things.  Does filteredRestaurants already contain restaurants before running this code?  If not, try:

Edit:  modified to only match restaurants that pass every filter condition.

```js
const restaurants = [
  {name: "r1", tags: ["fastfood", "chicken", "fish"]},
  {name: "r2", tags: ["steak", "chicken", "seafood"]},
  {name: "r3", tags: ["fastfood", "burger", "sandwich"]},
  {name: "r4", tags: ["steak", "burger", "sandwich"]}
];

const filters = ["steak", "seafood"];

let filteredRestaurants = restaurants.filter(r => filters.every(f => r.tags.includes(f)));

console.log(filteredRestaurants);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried using your implementation but everytime i try to press a filter button it gives me an empty array.

I forgot to mention that we are inside a computed property, dinamically rendered with VueJS and that the filters themselves change depending on what is pressed (are added or removed on the button press).

The splice part is there because after the first filtering if another filter is added I push the restaurant with the tag in with the first loop even if doesn't have the previous filter tags.

Still, I'm quite sure that I'm overcomplicating it.

Comment: You need to only find restaurants that match all the filters?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I might have solved my issue with a double splice check (I previously gave up on it because it occasionally spliced when it shouldn't,  because it wasn't in the correct order), but it's still an awful solution.
Im still looking for a cleaner way to do it :)

Comment: Try the modified code above

Comment: I tried it and it has the same result: an empty array.

Here is the console log after i click a button, filters and restaurants right before and filtered restaurants right after:

19:29:45.487
Array(5) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
 restaurants app.js:53697:15
19:29:45.488
Array [ "Breakfast" ]
 filters app.js:53698:15
19:29:45.489
Array []
 filtered app.js:53704:15

Comment: I don't know what your data looks like, take a look at the example and tell me what is different, or post your original data in the question.

Comment: I made a mistake in the question i asked, "tags" isn't an array of string, but an array of object.
I could try doing a computed property with a foreach loop to push their names to another array (something like stringifiedTags) and then I guess your method should work?